# Replacing variable with values from a CSV-file in python

Tags: python, variables, csv, header

I have a csv file with the following format:

```
variable,     name,   date,       location, youtube, 
 e1,      My birthday, 21st april, USA,    www.xyz.com
 e2,      your b'day,  1st May,   India,   www.abc.com
 e3,      christmas ,  25th Dec,  UK,      www.christmas.com
```

Here, the first row represents the header, `e1`, `e2` and `e3` are my variables.

Now I want to check if there is a variable called `e1.name` in some text and then I want to replace it by corresponding value i.e `My birthday`.

Similarly if there is a variable `e2.location`, then it must be replaced by `India`. Thus I want a kind of matrix like access.

Comment: I'm assuming it doesn't have all those spaces you've put in

Comment: yeah..no spaces, only put those to make the columns appear in a proper format

Comment: It's actually easier if you don't put them in, if people want to save your file they have to remove all the spaces

Comment: do you know how to do it? i need it urgently as a part of an open-source project I am working on.

Comment: we don't do urgent  here  but I have a solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import csv
with open('test.csv') as f:
    fieldnames = ('variable', 'name', 'date', 'location', 'youtube')
    r = csv.DictReader(f, fieldnames)
    next(f, None) # skip header
    rows = []
    for row in r:
        if row['variable'] == 'e1':
            row['name'] = 'My birthday'
        if row['variable'] == 'e2':
            row['location'] = 'India'
        rows.append(row)
    w = csv.DictWriter(a_file, fieldnames)
    w.writerows(rows)
```

If you want a matrix form, do something like this:

```
import csv
with open('test.csv') as f:
    next(f, None) # skip header
    rows = list(csv.reader(f))
    rows[0][1] = 'My birthday'
    rows[1][3] = 'India'
    w = csv.writer(a_file)
    w.writerows(rows)
```

Comment: Your solution would work, but I want to access them without using the variable names...Like a matrix form, access each cell as a[i][j]

Comment: @user1617731 Oh are you saying you know it will be that exact same file already? Only 3 variables?

Comment: @user1617731 You'll pretty much have to do the same thing, my first solution just does it in one pass